# I can't insert data inside the table using insert all

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE NEW(
ID NUMBER,
FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2(30),
LAST_NAME VARCHAR2(30),
MAJOR VARCHAR2(30)
);


INSERT ALL 
INTO NEW(ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,MAJOR) VALUES(1,'JOHN','BROWN','COMPUTER SCIENCE')
INTO NEW(ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,MAJOR) VALUES(2,'ALEXANDER','STAN','SINGER') 
INTO NEW(ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,MAJOR) VALUES(3,'JOHNNY','DEPP','STRIPPER') 
INTO NEW(ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,MAJOR) VALUES(4,'BRAD','PITT','PERFORMER')
SELECT* INTO DUAL;
```

Comment: What error message are you receiving?

Comment: This is the error messages that i received ORA-01744: inappropriate INTO
ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_190100", line 592
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_SQL", line 1658
ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_190100", line 578
ORA-06512: at "APEX_190100.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC", line 2033


3. INTO NEW(ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,MAJOR) VALUES(2,'ALEXANDER','STAN','SINGER') 
4. INTO NEW(ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,MAJOR) VALUES(3,'JOHNNY','DEPP','STRIPPER') 
5. INTO NEW(ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,MAJOR) VALUES(4,'BRAD','PITT','PERFORMER')
6. SELECT* INTO DUAL;

Comment: `SELECT* INTO DUAL` is not valid syntax. It should be `SELECT * FROM DUAL`

Comment: Thanks man for helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `INTO dual`, which is incorrect. It should be `from dual`;

```
SQL>
SQL> CREATE TABLE NEW(
  2  ID NUMBER,
  3  FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2(30),
  4  LAST_NAME VARCHAR2(30),
  5  MAJOR VARCHAR2(30)
  6  );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL>
SQL> INSERT ALL
  2  INTO NEW(ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,MAJOR) VALUES(1,'JOHN','BROWN','COMPUTER SCIENCE')
  3  INTO NEW(ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,MAJOR) VALUES(2,'ALEXANDER','STAN','SINGER')
  4  INTO NEW(ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,MAJOR) VALUES(3,'JOHNNY','DEPP','STRIPPER')
  5  INTO NEW(ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,MAJOR) VALUES(4,'BRAD','PITT','PERFORMER')
  6  SELECT * FROM DUAL;

4 rows created.

SQL>
```